# Converting onClick event to tap event of jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

```html
<input type="text" autofocus id="emailid"/>
<input type="button" value="@" id="@"  onclick="insertat()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  function insertat() {
    emailId.value += "@";
  }
</script>
```

I have a text box and a button with "@" symbol which when clicked inserts @ symbol in the text box.
However, The onClick event seems to respond slow and displays performance issues on Android tablets. How do i convert the onClick events to tap event using jQuery Mobile.

Any help would be appreciated.